# Is this a good approach for finding number of prime numbers within a certain range?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, primes

During my programming exam in college I was told to write a program that can find the prime numbers from 0 to n.

My approach was divide the numbers by 2,3,5 and 7, and the ones that doesn't returns a remainder of value 0 would be a prime number.

Is this a good approach for the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: It is just a wrong solution.

Comment: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Can you explaine why?

Comment: That works for n up to 120.

Comment: Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Comment: 121 would be the first non-prime listed as prime by your code. So your code  is only a solution up to n = 120.

Comment: There are a couple thousand questions about primes on SO.  I'd be surprised if there weren't at least a dozen that address roughly the same problem that you're asking about — and there are quite possibly several hundred of them.

Comment: ... something with logarithms ...

Comment: @wildplasser Could you elaborate?

Comment: @wildplasser . . . square roots, not logarithms.

Comment: Think about it like this: Why you are testing up to `7`? What is special about it comparing to the other primes? Hint: Nothing.

Comment: *Number* of primes *within a range*. Density/distance is proportional to ln(x) IIRc. On second thought: that was *only* the title ...

Comment: 2 divided by 2,3,5 and 7 and "doesn't returns a remainder of value 0 would be a prime number." classifies 2 as non-prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

121 = 11 * 11 would be the first non-prime listed as prime by your code.
So your code is only a solution up to n = 120.

I.e.: No.

Comment: thats brilliant catch

Comment: @EsmaeelE It is a good and accurate answer (so +1), but not even remotely "brilliant" (as I am sure Yunnosch would be the first to acknowledge). The question itself evinces a remarkable misunderstanding of relatively basic arithmetic, and counter-examples are trivially easy to find.

Comment: @JohnColeman :-) I was trying to answer a little more than the explicit question, while staying friendly - or at least matter of fact.